# Как удалить ведущие нули?

Tags: javascript

Этот код сравнивает положительные числа и отрицательные, но мне надо сделать так, чтобы код удалял нули отрицательных чисел внутри input, например: при введении "-02", стало: "-2".

```
        const fnum = document.querySelector('.fnum');
        const snum = document.querySelector('.snum');
        const button = document.querySelector('button');
        const compare = document.querySelector('.compare');
        const sc = document.querySelector('.sc');
        compare.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const num1 = parseFloat(clearZeros(fnum.value));
            const num2 = parseFloat(clearZeros(snum.value));
            if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
                sc.innerText = 'Введите корректные числа';
            } else {
                if (num1 > num2) {
                    sc.innerText = '>';
                } else if (num1 === num2) {
                    sc.innerText = '=';
                } else {
                    sc.innerText = '<';
                }
            }
        });
        const clearZeros = (str) => {
            let arr = str.split('');
            let isNegative = false;
            if (arr[0] === '-') {
                isNegative = true;
                arr.shift();
            }
            while (arr[0] === '0') {
                arr.shift();
            }
            if (isNegative) {
                arr.unshift('-');
            }
            return arr.join('');
        };
```

Я пытался сделать, но не получается.

Comment: а просто ``const num1 = parseFloat(fnum.value);`` разве не дает нужный результат?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте регулярные выражения.
Метод `replace()` **однократно** (только первое найденное вхождение) заменяет найденные символы во входящей строке, соответствующие регулярному выражению `(?<=^|-)0+`, на `пусто`, т.е. удаляет их из текста. Метод не изменяет входящую строку, а возвращает модифицированную.
Регулярное выражение состоит из:

- позитивного просмотра назад `(?<=^|-)`, которым определяется наличие
  начала строки `^` или (`|`) дефиса `-`.
  и
- последовательности нулей `0+`.

Если по-простому, то *найти первую серию нулей, следующую за началом строки или дефисом, и удалить её*.

```js
['102', '-0023', '057'].forEach(x => console.log(x.replace(/(?<=^|-)0+/, '')))
```

Comment: Можно подробнее?